# Is there a way to deserialize my JSON without using a wrapper class for each item?

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I am developing an ASP.NET application using JSON.NET that interfaces with a third-party REST API. The API returns JSON in the following format:

```
[
    {
        user: {
            id: 12345,
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Smith",
            created_at: "11/12/13Z00:00:00"
        }
    },
    {
        user: {
            id: 12346,
            first_name: "Bob",
            last_name: "Adams",
            created_at: "12/12/13Z00:00:00"
        }
    }
]
```

The `user` field is redundant, but I do not have control over the API so I have to live with it. I am currently using the following code to deserialize the JSON:

```
// Deserialize
var responseBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<UserWrapper>>(responseString);

// Access Properties
foreach (var userWrapper in responseBody)
{
    var firstName = userWrapper.User.FirstName
}

// Model classes
public class UserWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Having the wrapper class is a little ugly. So my question is:

**Is there a way to eliminate the wrapper class using JSON.NET?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating a custom converter for your `User` class and using that during deserialization.  The converter code might look something like this:

```
class UserConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(User));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject wrapper = JObject.Load(reader);
        return wrapper["user"].ToObject<User>();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("user");
        writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Keep the `User` class exactly as you defined it (with all the `JsonProperty` decorations).
You can then deserialize your JSON and access properties like this:

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(responseString, new UserConverter());

foreach (var user in users)
{
    var firstName = user.FirstName
    // etc...
}
```

The `UserWrapper` class is no longer needed and can be deleted.

**EDIT**

Important note: the above solution will **NOT** work if you decorate your `User` class with the `[JsonConverter]` attribute.  This is because the custom converter as written uses a second copy of the serializer to handle the `User` deserialization once we've gone down a level to get to the real user data.  If you decorate the class, then all copies of the serializer will try to use the converter and you'll end up with a self-referencing loop.

If you would rather use the `[JsonConverter]` attribute, then the custom converter class will have to handle deserialization of all the properties of the `User` class manually.  Taking this approach, the code would look like this instead:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JObject wrapper = JObject.Load(reader);
    JToken user = wrapper["user"];
    return new User
    {
        ID = user["id"].Value<string>(),
        FirstName = user["first_name"].Value<string>(),
        LastName = user["last_name"].Value<string>(),
        CreatedAt = user["created_at"].Value<DateTime>()
    };
}

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    User user = (User)value;
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("user");
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WritePropertyName("id");
    writer.WriteValue(user.ID);
    writer.WritePropertyName("first_name");
    writer.WriteValue(user.FirstName);
    writer.WritePropertyName("last_name");
    writer.WriteValue(user.LastName);
    writer.WritePropertyName("created_at");
    writer.WriteValue(user.CreatedAt);
    writer.WriteEndObject();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

The obvious problem with this approach is that you sacrifice a little bit of maintainability: if you ever add more properties to your `User` class, you have to remember to change your `UserConverter` to match.

Comment: How can I implement the WriteJson method? I have attempted to use the writer to write the user property and then use the serializer to serialize the value, but this results in a self referencing loop because the serializer just uses calls WriteJson on another UserConverter. See code:

Comment: You are close-- just use a new serializer instead of the one passed in.  The new one will not have a reference to the converter so you won't have the circular reference problem.  I've updated my answer with the code.  The only downside is it will not pick up any of the other serializer settings you may be using-- if you need those, you'll have to manually copy them from the outer serializer to the inner.

Comment: Actually, the ReadJson method you provided has the same problem. The call to the ToObject method just calls ReadJson again.

Comment: Really? I tested that code, and it worked for me without issue.

Comment: Well, instead of passing the new UserConverter to the DeserializeObject method, I am using the JsonConverter attribute on the User class. Let me try it the way you provided.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that will not work.  If you put the attribute on the class then all copies of the serializer will use the converter.  So then you'll have the circular reference problem no matter what you do.  The only way around would be to manually handle all the user properties individually inside your converter.

Comment: Just for reference, I added new versions of the `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` methods which show how to handle the `User` object properties manually.  This version would be compatible with the `[JsonConvert]` attribute, but the tradeoff is you now have two classes to maintain going forward.  Also, ironically, the `[JsonProperty]` attributes end up being ignored.